# Showdownjs makeMarkdown configuration

Tags: javascript, showdown

I'm trying to use showdownjs to convert HTML to markdown using `converter.makeMarkdown(html)`. Unfortunately, there isn't much documentation on the library package and it doesn't seem to be converting `<br/>` `<u>` or `<span style="xxx"></span>` tags into valid markdown.

I was wondering if there are configuration options I can set which handle transforming these tags into valid markdown?

Have tried setting a few options with `coverter.setOption(xxx,xxx)`, however these attemps have failed to produce adequate markdown output.